# LogParser for Java

Tags: java, sql, logging, logparser

I just read [this post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/08/microsoft-logparser.html) and i wonder if there is something like this for querying jboss log file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Chainsaw V2 - the supported expression syntax used to filter, search and colorize rows isn't SQL based, but provides a good amount of functionality (regexp queries, exists (not null), relational operators, etc).

You can view information on the expression syntax from the help/tutorial menu.

Chainsaw V2's home page:
http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/

You can run Chainsaw V2 via web start from the 'download' link on that page.

Answer (score 5):

I'm developing [OtrosLogViewer](http://code.google.com/p/otroslogviewer/), it's on apache license. It's a quite good log viewer with similar features to Chainsaw.

Answer (score 2):

JBoss logs using [Log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/), and [Chainsaw](http://logui.sourceforge.net/) is a parser/GUI for Log4j